# Why this code doesn't give any output? It seems like an infinite loop

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, exe

I have to make a program that reads from a .dat file that has two columns. I am interested in only one. It has multiple sets of 120 elements, so I want to divide the file into groups of 120 elements and calculate the average of each group. The code is this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int i, k=0;
double temp [120];
double tmean, total=0;

int main()
{

    ifstream fin ("P01-05 tensione di vapore di riferimento fino 180°C.dat");

    if (!fin)
    {
        cerr << "\nErrore: non si puo aprire il file.\n" << endl;
    exit(1);
    }

    string line;

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("tmean.dat", ios::out);
    fout << "Tmean" << endl;

    while (fin >> std::skipws && !fin.eof())
    {
       for(i=0; i<120; i++)
       {
           getline(fin,line);
           istringstream ss(line);    

           double col1;      
           double col2;      

           ss >> col1;   //col1=TIME
           ss >> col2;   //col2=TEMPERATURE

           temp[i] = col2;
           total += temp[i];
           k++;

       }

       tmean = total/k;

       fout << tmean << endl;       
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I've compiled and executed it but it doesn't work, it acts like it is an infinite loop. It doesn't give me any output. Why?

Comment: Is there anything in the tmean.dat file after the execution? Does it have Tmean line?

Comment: @SashaPachev No it doesn't open the file tmean.dat because i thing the program results in an infinite loop!

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Added print statements to show intermediate steps? These are all basic debugging steps you should do before posting here.

Comment: First, remove the spaces from the input file name. Second, run your code step-by-step using a debugger. *Then* you should ask around, if you're still stuck. Also look at creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your data file is missing.

Comment: @pcarter sorry i am a beginner in c++, i'll do these debugging steps.

Comment: There isn't any infinite loop in your code, you must be misinterpreting what you are seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you're a beginner, here's some code showing how to check your input operations succeed, and otherwise output some useful error messages to help you find the offending lines in the file.

Notes:

- The "[i]" values in error messages are relative line number within the "group" currently being read, and not absolute line numbers from the start of the file.
- Blank lines are only accepted between groups (the `std::skipws` will jump over that).
- The use of a macro for `FATAL` may be confusing: summarily, only macros can accept arguments like `"i " << i` and add them to a streaming operation.  The `do {` ... `} while (false)` thing is a standard way to wrap a macro so it works properly in `if else` statements: you can search for details on that if you are curious.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#define FATAL(MSG) \
    do { \
        std::cerr << "Errore: " << MSG << '\n'; \
        exit(1); \
    } while (false)

int main()
{
    if (std::ifstream fin{"P01-05 tensione di vapore di riferimento fino 180°C.dat"})
    {
        if (std::ofstream fout{"tmean.dat"})
        {
            fout << "Tmean\n";
            while (fin >> std::skipws && !fin.eof())
            {
                const int group_size = 120;
                double temp[group_size];
                double total = 0;
                for (int i=0; i < group_size; ++i)
                {
                    std::string line;
                    if (getline(fin, line))
                    {
                        std::istringstream ss(line);
                        double time;
                        if (ss >> time >> temp[i])
                            total += temp[i];
                        else
                            FATAL("unable to parse 2 doubles from line '"
                                  << line << "' for [" << i << ']');
                    }
                    else
                        // will rarely happen after checking !eof()
                        FATAL("failed to read needed line from file for ["
                              << i << ']');
                }
                double tmean = total / group_size;
                fout << tmean << '\n';       
            }
        }
        else
            FATAL("could not open output file.");
    }
    else
        FATAL("non si puo aprire il file.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So the macro MSG has a debugging function? If you want, to be more complete, i can attach the file .dat from which i read the values.

Comment: I've tried to compile the code you suggested me but it gives error at line 14 where there is the first if with the function ifstream. it gives this error:       '[Error] in C++98 'fin' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}''

Comment: @PaoloOrsatti: this code uses the C++11 Standard (from 2011) - if your compiler's using the 1998 Standard it won't work.  If you're using GNU or clang, try adding `-std=c++11` to the compilation command line, or reading your compiler or IDE documentation.  If that's too much hassle, try changing the `{` and `}` to `(` and `)`.  Cheers

Comment: I've tried to add _-std=c++11_ to the command line but it gives me the error that it doesn't recognized the command line option.  I've also changed the_{_ and _} in _(_ and _)_ but it returns me another error:           ' [Error] expected primary-expression before 'fin' '.

Comment: @PaoloOrsatti: which compiler and version are you using?  Meanwhile, you can use `std::ifstream fin("P01-05 tensione di vapore di riferimento fino 180°C.dat"); if (fin) ...` and similar for `fout`.

Comment: Finally it works! I've only changed the while condition using `getline(fin, line)` instead of `(fin >> std::skipws && !fin.eof())` and in the if conditions i put `(fin.is_open())` and `(fout.is_open())`. Thank you very much TonyD!